# How to check application is in background?

Tags: android

I want to know how to start 1 activity every time when application is in background or when we tap on launch icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods in your activity according to  your needs 
Check this link: [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: well , u can come up with ideas , but it depends on the implementation and application needs